# asp.net c# webpage transforming url redirecting issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, transformation, global-asax

i am running asp.net c# website and i have tags page. i transform tag page url in global.asax and that new url is working but when i click on page 2 button then url redirecting.
here is new url
`http://localhost:25878/Tag/Applications`

here when click on next page then url is showing this format
`http://localhost:25878/Tag/Applications?Tag=Applications`

pagination is gridview auto pagination which is not showing any page numbers in url.
here is my global.asax code

```cs
if (oldpath.Contains("/tag/"))
{
    string[] words = oldpath.Split('/');
    string lastword = words[words.Length - 1];
    newpath = "/Tags.aspx?Tag=" + lastword;
}
```

here is my tags.aspx.cs file code

```cs
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = FormSQL();
}
```

i am trying that new transform url must not redirect when click on next page.
evan i can change this pagination style if not possible with this pagination. Please help to fix this and if not possible then you can help me to explain how can i change pagination style and add page parameters in url.